# read an unformatted text file and store its value in hashmap

Tags: java

I have a text file containing data in below format

```
  Vehicle:Bike
  MOdel:FZ
  Make:
  Yamaha
  Description
  abcdefgh
  ijklmn
  problems
  gear problem, fork bend.

  this is auto data
  ***********************************end***********************
  Vehicle:Bike
  MOdel:R15
  Make:
  Yamaha
  Description
  1234,
  567.
  890
  problems
  gear problem, fork bend.
  oil leakage

  this is auto data
  ***********************************end***********************
```

i have given 2 datas but there are many more such in a text file i want to read it and store it in a hashmap such that

```
  Bike:FZ:Yamaha:abcdefghijklmn:gear problem,fork bend.
  Bike:R15:Yamaha:1234,567.890:gear problem,fork bend.oil leakage
```

My sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));

            String sCurrentLine;
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            hmap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                sCurrentLine = sCurrentLine.trim();
                if (!sCurrentLine.equals("")) // don't write out blank lines
                {
                    if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("***********")) {
                        i++;
                    } else {

                        if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("Vehicle:")) {
                            String[] veh = sCurrentLine.split(":");
                            String vehicle = tType[1];
                        }
                        if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("Model:")) {
                            String[] mod = sCurrentLine.split(":");
                            String model = iShield[1];
                        }  
                        hmap.put(0,i+":"+vehicle+":"+model);                      
                    }
                }
j++;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

not sure how to read ---> make, description & problems attributes.

Comment: Your question is missing the "question part". I don't understand what the map key should be, what the values should be. Is your problem with "parsing" the incoming strings?! Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an `ObjectInputStream`.

An example:

```
/* Create an ObjectInputStream for your text file
 * and a hash map to store the values in. */
ObjectInputStream obj = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(textFile));
hmap = (HashMap<String, String>) obj.readObject(); // I assume you want strings.
hmap.put("value", var); // Var can be whatever other strings you created.
// It is always a good idea to close streams.
obj.close();
```

Just remember that, if you need another variable type placed into the hash map, you can create it with something like `HashMap<String, byte[]>`.

Obviously, you'll need to implement your already-created methods to determine each variable.

If I have not been specific enough, or have missed something important, let me know.